# not able to connect to server

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

Hello everyone I am new to coding. I want to run my python file on the command line. In order to do that I first  execute:

```
docker image build -t se .
```

start the container using:

```
docker container run --rm -it --name se -p 5432:5432 se
```

this enabled me to connect to PostgreSQL on port 5432.

I get following message on my command line :

```
2019-11-28 18:50:01.004 UTC [32] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2019-11-28 18:50:01.005 UTC [32] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-11-28 18:50:01.006 UTC [32] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 39) exited with exit code 1
2019-11-28 18:50:01.067 UTC [34] LOG:  shutting down
2019-11-28 18:50:01.090 UTC [32] LOG:  database system is shut down
done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2019-11-28 18:50:01.124 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-11-28 18:50:01.124 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-11-28 18:50:01.125 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-11-28 18:50:01.137 UTC [55] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-11-28 18:50:01 UTC
2019-11-28 18:50:01.140 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

**After this I open another command window and run my python file assuming that my server is working**

```
MacBook-Pro:Desktop nousheen$ python3 juiceboard.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "juiceboard.py", line 13, in <module>
    table = juicetables[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not sure what to do here. Can someone please help me ????

Comment: better you put the steps for reproduce the issue, then it's easy to help you.

Comment: Are you containerizing both your python app and postgres? Did you make your own Dockerfile for the postgres container? Are you able to connect to postgres from outside python with something like pgadmin? Needs a little more detail.

Comment: Are you containerizing both your python app and postgres? Yes I am.                            Did you make your own Dockerfile for the postgres container? Yes.                               Are you able to connect to postgres from outside python with something like pgadmin? No

Comment: If you are new to programming, and just want to run a script, do not use Docker.  It adds a _lot_ of complexity that you don't need at this point.  It looks like you're on an OS X host, and that comes with a `/usr/bin/python3` preinstalled; you can use that for development without needing Docker.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. I was able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Xetera. I was able to figure out the problem. It's working now.